# Java Math.exp(double) vs StrictMath.exp(double)

Tags: java, math

I have a very simple `Java` test case which calls `Math.exp(double)` and then `StrictMath.exp(double)` and for a reason I can't understand the result is different on `Java 8` despite the fact that from `JDK` source code it appears that `Math.exp` simply delegates to `StrictMath.exp`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    System.out.println(p.get("java.runtime.version"));
    System.out.println(p.get("java.specification.version"));
    System.out.println(Math.exp(1d));
    System.out.println(StrictMath.exp(1d));
}
```

result on `Java 8`:

```
1.8.0_66-b18
1.8
null
2.718281828459045
2.7182818284590455
```

and on `Java 7`:

```
1.7.0_21-b11
1.7
2.7182818284590455
2.7182818284590455
```

Any pointers appreciated, more out of curiosity than any real issue.

Comment: And also `Math.exp(1d) == StrictMath.exp(1d)` --> `false`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410559/why-does-math-sin-delegate-to-strictmath-sin is also a good description.

Answer (score 2):

This question is essentially the opposite of the question Joe linked to: [java.lang.Math.log replaced by intrinsic call, why not java.lang.Math.exp()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085294/java-lang-math-log-replaced-by-intrinsic-call-why-not-java-lang-math-exp)

Before [revision 6759698e3140](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/rev/6759698e3140) `Math.exp()` was not replaced at runtime by an [intrinsic call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function), meaning it delegated to `StrictMath.exp()`.  After that revision (and therefore all of Java 8) it is possible that `Math.exp()` will give a different result because the JVM will optimize the calls.

Conceptually you can think of `Math` as providing "fast" functions, and `StrictMath` providing "correct" functions.  `Math` falls back to `StrictMath` when it can do no better, but the guarantees about `Math`'s behavior are weaker than `StrictMath`'s, and therefore can be optimized (potentially at the cost of some limited correctness) more than `StrictMath`.